# Convert base-64 string to Blob in your LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, blob, base64

**Requirement** :
I need to get **Blob** Data from my **File** (represented as `ContentDocument`) in my **LWC**.

Currently I **implemented** it in next way :

- I have an **Apex method** which returns **base-64 string** for specific `ContentDocument` :

```java
public with sharing class ShowBlobDataController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String getBlobContent( String docId ){
        try {
            ContentVersion contVers = [SELECT VersionData FROM ContentVersion where ContentDocumentId =: docId LIMIT 1];
            Blob contVersBlob = contVers.VersionData;
            return EncodingUtil.base64Encode(contVersBlob);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I call this **Apex method** after pressing a button in my **LWC** and decode the result into `Blob` in next way :

```js
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import getBlobContent from '@salesforce/apex/ShowBlobDataController.getBlobContent'; // import Apex method from LWC
    
export default class ShowBlobData extends LightningElement {
    @api docId ; // we get this value from parent LWC
    getDocContentType( docId ){ /* some logic */ }; // this method returns Content Type for specific Document 

    // JS method on which we call Apex method to get Blob
    async getBlobContentHandler(){
        // helper JS function for Decodindg base64Data to BLOB
        const b64toBlob = (b64Data, contentType='', sliceSize=512) => {
            const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
            const byteArrays = [];
            for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
                const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);
                const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
                for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
                    byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
                }
                const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
                byteArrays.push(byteArray);
            }
            const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
            return blob;
        }
        // getting Blob data from Apex
        await getBlobContent( { docId: this.docId }).then( (base64Data) => {
            const contentType = this.getDocContentType( this.docId ); // getting document Content Type
            const blob = b64toBlob(base64Data, contentType); // getting Blob Data 
            
            // all other logic
            // all other logic
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        })
    }
}
```

I have implemented this **decoding** logic based on **the answer** to the question :
[Creating a BLOB from a Base64 string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript)

So my **question** is :

Is there more **accurate/easier** method to get **Blob** Content from **Apex** to **LWC**.

*Any help will be appreciated.*
*Thank you.*

Comment: Aside from the conversion issue, reading the document into memory (via `VersionData`) only works for small documents. If your ultimate goal is to have the end-user download the document, then [here's a good approach](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/342372/how-to-generate-a-pdf-and-have-it-download-from-a-lightning-web-component)

Comment: @identigral thank you for the information, however it is not the case for me.